# How to classify data which doesn't match any label

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm creating a supervised convnet which recognize a phrase in a regional language.

For example:

I have a dataset which contains 100 sounds for labels A and another 100 sounds for labels B. Now normal operation of the network is to differentiate a sound between label A and label B.

But let's say that I give a new sound to the network to classify which is actually neither A nor B. Now I want the neural net to tell me that it doesn't qualify any of the labels.

How can I achieve this?

Can you please point me to the right direction for this kind of usage.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Basically when you have a NN, you have an output layer that does nothing except of giving you a **probability** of whether your input is predicted to belong to either of your classes (that are supported by your NN).

So if the prediction (on a praticular input) gives you low enough probabilities for all of your classes (it's up to you to define the threashold) you can say that the input does not match any of your classes.

**UPD:**
Try [this course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) to get introduced to machine learning approaches and the math paradigms that underly those approaches. There is step-by-step introduction from the very basic conceptions and pratical exercises. There are a lot of basic things to know before start playing with NNs.

Comment: I'll try it out! As far a i can recall, the sum of those probabilities is 1. isn't it?

Comment: The sum of the probabilities is 1. The NN tells you that whether your new input has higher correlation(score) of A or B. In the case that your new input is neither A and B, the result tells you that which the input is more likely to be. 
The solution of setting a threshold can be reliable if the input has low correlation to both A and B. You can either optimize the threshold or you can also create another class C and label it with arbitrary sounds( other random words or maybe even noise?).

Comment: @penduDev Sure the sum of probabilities is 1. This means if you have a binary classification problem (if the output is A?) and the prediction gives you 0.25, that only means that with 75% you have something different to A. If you have classification of A, B and C all three of them might get probability 0.1. That only means that the network cannot recognize the input and the result does not belong to either of those three classes. (basically is depends on the approach you are using to multi-class classfication problem)

Comment: @YiruiJiang can you please tell me how can I set threshold on a network, I don't want to create another class C

Comment: @AlexeyR. I just confirmed that if I use softmax function, then the sum of prob is always when when binary classification or multi-class. However the logits(1 step before softmax) is different and doesn't sum up to 1. So I can probably set the threshold at the logits step. But how exactly can I go about doing it?

Comment: @penduDev sorry, I'm not the one you asked (about the threashold), however there is no some special settings. It's all about how you treat the output of your output layer. There would be some interface (probably UI or WS) layer wrapper for your NN where you could interprete the results in order to be understood by a consumer.

Comment: @AlexeyR. oops! my comment was a bit late. I'm still trying to figure out how exactly can I set the threshold..can you point me to some resource where I can read more about interpreting results of NN

Comment: Thanks! will check that out..I prbly need to learn more clearly about the basic concepts first!